# Como passar parâmetros para um Makefile

Tags: python, django, docker, makefile

Eu estou desenvolvendo um app django no docker e para não ter que ficar digitando  `docker-compose exec djangoapp python manage.py <alguma coisa>` eu escrevi um Makefile para rodar os comandos que eu mais uso. Só que que não sei como fazer o Makefile pegar os parâmetros que eu passo para para ele.

Por exemplo: Eu consigo rodar o migrate assim `make migrate` com o meu Makefile mas não consigo consigo criar um novo app assim `make startapp novoapp`. A minha pergunta é como eu faço o Makefile pegar os parâmetros que eu passa para ele?

O meu Makefile é:

```
COMPOSE=docker-compose
DJANGOAPP=$(COMPOSE) exec djangoapp python manage.py


build:
    $(COMPOSE) build

up:
    $(COMPOSE) up

start:
    $(COMPOSE) up -d

down:
    $(COMPOSE) down

restart: down start

migrate:
    $(DJANGOAPP) migrate

makemigrations:
    $(DJANGOAPP) migrations

startapp:
    $(DJANGOAPP) startapp

startproject:
    $(DJANGOAPP) startproject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826178/2099835), você só pode passar variáveis de ambiente para o Makefile. Exemplo:

Makefile:

```
startapp:
    $(DJANGOAPP) startapp $(nome_app)
```

Linha de comando:

```
make startapp nome_app=novoapp
```

Porém isso não é muito intuitívo, pois você precisa definir todos os argumentos individualmente para cada comando.

Para fazer isso que você deseja, ao invés de criar um Makefile, eu uso um alias para esses comandos mais comuns, possibilitando usar os comandos de acordo com o que preciso:

Trecho de código carregado no `~/.bashrc` (eu gosto de deixar separado num arquivo `.bash_aliases`):

```
alias dup='docker-compose up'
alias dcb='docker-compose build'
alias dcr='docker-compose run --rm'
alias dce='docker-compose exec'

# pode usar um alias dentro do alias
alias django='dcr djangoapp python manage.py'

# por gosto pessoal, gosto de deixar o comando completo no alias, 
# para não criar dependências entre os alias, tem suas 
# vantagens e desvantagens 
alias djangoexec='docker-compose exec djangoapp python manage.py'
```

Com isso, depois de atualizar minha sessão do bash (`source ~/.bashrc`), posso executar:

```
# Obs: com o run --rm não preciso dar um up no docker-compose antes
django startapp novoapp

dcb

# Exemplo com parâmetros
dup -d
djangoexec startapp novoapp
```

Outro macete que uso bastante é o [history do bash](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44997/how-to-use-bash-history-to-improve-your-command-line-productivity/). Para não precisar adicionar todos os comandos como um alias, eu busco outros comando que já executei anteriormente com `CTRL` + `R`. Se depois de um tempo eu percebesse que esse era um comando recorrente, ai eu criava um alias.

Comment: alias... Boa! Eu nem pensei nisso, fui direto para o Makefile. Valeu pela dica!